# Object.assign not copying as expected in loop

Tags: javascript

Im iterating over an array of objects. In my loop I want to only copy one key value pair and push it into a summaryList array. I'm having trouble understanding why `cusipObj` is still equal to item. I would expect only `item.Cusip` to live in the `cusipObj`.

Originally, I tried using the lodash `pick` method and ran into the same issue.

I understand that objects get passed by reference, but I was under the impression that `Object.assign` solves this issue. Can someone clarify how I can only copy the `item.Cusip` value into a new Object? What am I doing wrong?

```
list = [{  
   Id:90,
   Cusip:"114760EM9",
   UserQuantity:null,
   UserPrice:null,
   UserSettlementDate:null
}]


summaryList = [];

list.forEach((item) => {
  let cusipObj = Object.assign({Cusip: item.Cusip}, item);
  console.log(cusipObj);
  summaryList.push(cusipObj);
})
```

Comment: please add `list` and the wanted result as well.

Comment: Note that converting every item is the reason that `map` exists.  It's more clear than your `forEach` implementation.

Comment: If you want only that value, why are you using `Object.assign(..., item)`, which will copy all keys?

Comment: This is really strange line of code `Object.assign({Cusip: item.Cusip}, item)` you first copy one property, then the rest. If you need to shallow clone `Object.assign({}, item)`. If you need a single property just do `{ Cusip: item.Cusip}`

Comment: @ScottSauyet I originally used map, but got the same results

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I was referencing the mdn documentation on `Object.assign`

const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = Object.assign({c: 4, d: 5}, object1);

console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
// expected output: 3 5

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, Im only copy `item.Cusip` from the item object into a new object(cusipObj)

Comment: If you copy a single property you don't need `Object.assign`, just create a new object `{Cusip: item.Cusip}`

Comment: Well, `map` probably wasn't your issue.  It seems to be a misunderstanding of what `assign` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need just to map the wanted property.

```js
var list = [{ Id: 90, Cusip: "114760EM9", UserQuantity: null, UserPrice: null, UserSettlementDate: null }],
    summaryList = list.map(({ Cusip }) => ({ Cusip }));

console.log(summaryList);
```

As mentioned in the comments, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign({Cusip: item.Cusip}, item);
```

assigns to the single property the whole object which leads to the same object with all properties as before.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` copies *all properties* from the source arguments to the target. The target is the first argument, and the source arguments are all the others.

In your example, you're assigning *all the properties* of `item` to the `{Cusip: item.Cusip}` object, so the result of `Object.assign` has the exact same shape as `item`.

Here's a concrete example:

```js
const foo = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
const fooAssigned = Object.assign({ foo: 'foo' }, foo)
console.log(fooAssigned) // { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
```

If your intention is to just pick out the `Cusip` property, you can just do this:

```
summaryList = [];

list.forEach((item) => {
  let cusipObj = {Cusip: item.Cusip}
  console.log(cusipObj);
  summaryList.push(cusipObj);
})
```

Or even more succinctly

```js
const list = [{  
       Id:90,
       Cusip:"114760EM9",
       UserQuantity:null,
       UserPrice:null,
       UserSettlementDate:null
    }]
       
const summaryList = list.map(item => ({ Cusip: item.Cusip }))

console.log(summaryList)
```